# Comma separated ID column having values identical

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, string-aggregation

I got so many solutions to merge values by comma.
I have some tricky requirement of merging ids by comma. I have around 10 columns in a table. For eg.

```
     declare  @t1 TABLE (id INT, NAME VARCHAR(MAX), address1 varchar(max), mobileno varchar(max));
     INSERT @t1 values (1,'100',null,'1111111111');
     INSERT @t1 values (2,'100','pune','1111111111');
     INSERT @t1 values (3,'200',null,null);
     INSERT @t1 values (4,'300','pune',null);
     INSERT @t1 values (5,'200',null,'1111111111');

    SELECT 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ','+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()] 
    FROM @t1 as B
    WHERE B.NAME = A.NAME
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as ID, NAME, address1, mobileno
    FROM @t1 as A
   GROUP BY NAME, address1, mobileno
```

For eg.

```
ID | Value
---+-------
 1 | 100
 2 | 100
 3 | 200  
 4 | 200
 5 | 300
```

I need output like

```
ID | Value
---|------
1,2| 100
3,4| 200
  5| 300
```

Comment: This isn't unusual.  Google:  SQL Server string aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

```
--sample table:
WITH ABC
AS
(
SELECT '1' as ID, '100' as value

UNION 

SELECT '2' as ID, '100' as value

UNION 

SELECT '3' as ID, '200' as value

UNION 

SELECT '4' as ID, '200' as value

UNION 

SELECT '5' as ID, '300' as value


)
--Expected query:
SELECT 
STUFF((
SELECT ','+ID 
FROM ABC as B
WHERE B.Value = A.Value
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as ID, Value
FROM ABC as A
GROUP BY Value

--Desired output:
    ID  Value
    1,2 100
    3,4 200
    5   300
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** The `','+ ID` must make sure ID is in `VARCHAR` or similar string type, otherwise need to convert before it works correctly.